# Export nodes palette SPSS Modeler

Tags: spss, spss-modeler

I was using SPSS Modeler on my home PC and I made some custom nodes palettes. I was wondering if there is a way to export the nodes palette to get on another computer?

Answer (score 0):

Check the reference from IBM Knowlegde Center at [Ref from IBM](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS3RA7_17.1.0/modeler_r_nodes_ddita/spss/base/uibuilder_manage.html)

Manually copying an installed custom node dialog
By default, the specifications for an installed custom node dialog are stored in the CDB/ folder of the installation directory. You can copy this folder to the same relative location in another instance of IBM SPSS Modeler and it will be recognized as an installed node dialog the next time that instance is launched.

If you specify alternative locations for installed nodedialogs--using the IBM_SPSS_MODELER_EXTENSION_PATH environment variable--then copy the  folder from the appropriate alternate location.
If alternative locations for installed node dialogs have been defined for the instance of IBM SPSS Modeler you are copying to, then you can copy to any one of the specified locations and the node dialog will be recognized as an installed node dialog the next time that instance is launched.